# Rust Generic Vector<Vector<T>>

Tags: vector, rust

I'm trying to work my way up to rust and I'm stuck on a thing with generic types.
Surely you know the example from chapter 10.1 (Generic Data Types). I would like to create a vector that contains both the i32 vector and the char vector. 
But somehow I can't get it to work.

```
fn largest<T: PartialOrd + Copy>(list: &[T]) -> T {
    let mut largest = list[0];

    for &item in list.iter() {
        if item > largest {
            largest = item;
        }
    }

    largest
}

fn main() {
    let number_list = vec![34, 50, 25, 100, 65];

    let result = largest(&number_list);
    println!("The largest number is {}", result);

    let char_list = vec!['y', 'm', 'a', 'q'];

    let result = largest(&char_list);
    println!("The largest char is {}", result);
}
```

I would now like to create a vector

```
let mut vecvec = Vec<Vec<T>>::new();
vecvec.push(number_list);
vecvec.push(char_list);
```

unfortunately, it doesn't work. I hope you have advice.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, "it doesn't work" is *never helpful*. It obviously "doesn't work" or you wouldn't be asking for help.

Second, providing the code you're actually working with (on the playground) is much easier than having to guess where the code "which doesn't work" is supposed to go.

Third,

> ```
> let mut vecvec = Vec<Vec<T>>::new();
> ```

`T` needs to be defined somewhere, and it needs to be something that makes sense.

> ```
> vecvec.push(number_list);
> vecvec.push(char_list);
> ```

`Vec<T>` means all elements of a vec must have the same type. Here you have a `Vec<i32>` and a `Vec<char>`. They're not the same type and they *can not be reconciled* to the same type, so they can't be put in the same vector: Rust does not have ubiquitous type erasure or a "root type" à la Java, you can't just say that you have "a vector of vectors" and leave it at that with the blanks being filled at runtime.

This means you need some sort of indirection to "hide" the divergence, either an enum with a variant for each type of vec you want:

```rust
enum Wrapper {
    Numbers(Vec<i32>),
    Chars(Vec<char>)
}
```

Or a trait through which you can then use a *trait object*.

Comment: Hello Masklinn,
thank you for the quick feedback. Sorry for the incorrectly constructed question, try to improve my question in the future.
Yes, I understand that a vector can only contain one data type. But since the vector is a heap datatype, the vector itself is an address, at least my understanding. For this reason I assumed that a vector can create a datatype which contains addresses. But now, after further reading, I think that I have to put it into a box. Am I right?
Thanks again for the quick answer. Stay healthy.

Comment: @DusanDjordjevic: In a strongly typed language, such as Rust, saying _the vector itself is an address_ is not a good idea: a vector is an address *and a type* (and a few other things). Likewise, a `Box` is not just an address, it is an address and a type.

Comment: A vector is a type and a structure, it's not just a pointer to some random area on the heap which is equivalent to any other area on the heap. So two vectors of different concrete types (vecs with different `T`s) are essentially unrelated and can not be mixed without a "compatibility layer" of sorts, like an enum, or a trait object. A Box would do nothing on its own, you'd have a `Box<Vec<i32>>` and a `Box<Vec<char>>`, still unrelated. At best it would be a way to create a boxed trait object.

Comment: "First, "it doesn't work" is never helpful. It obviously "doesn't work" or you wouldn't be asking for help." First this should be a comment under the question. "Second, providing the code you're actually working with (on the playground) is much easier than having to guess where the code "which doesn't work" is supposed to go." this too

Answer (score 1):

everybody,
here is the code that has now been created with the help of the answers. In case someone comes up with such an obscure idea ;)

```
fn largest<T: PartialOrd + Copy>(list: &[T]) -> T {
    let mut largest = list[0];

    for &item in list.iter() {
        if item > largest {
            largest = item;
        }
    }

    largest
}

enum Wrapper {
    Numbers(Vec<i32>),
    Chars(Vec<char>)
}


fn main() {
    let mut number_list = vec![34, 50, 25, 100, 65];

    let result = largest(&number_list);
    println!("The largest number is {}", result);

    let mut char_list = vec!['y', 'm', 'a', 'q'];

    let result = largest(&char_list);
    println!("The largest char is {}", result);

    let mut vec: Vec<Wrapper> = Vec::new();

    vec.push(Wrapper::Numbers(number_list));
    vec.push(Wrapper::Chars(char_list));

    for v in vec.iter() {
        match v {
            Wrapper::Numbers(o) =>{ println!("The largest  is {}", largest(o))},
            Wrapper::Chars(c) => println!("The largest  is {}", largest(c))
        }

    }

}
```